# How to set the custom font for UIAlertAciton in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

```
 let alertcontroller = UIAlertController(title: "try", message: "now", preferredStyle: .alert)
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Some title", style: .destructive, handler: nil)
    let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "New User")

    let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedText.length)
    attributedText.addAttribute(NSKernAttributeName, value: 1.5, range: range)
    attributedText.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25.0), range: range)
    action.setValue(UIColor(hex: 0xFF9B05),forKey: "titleTextColor")
    alertcontroller.addAction(action)
```

Comment: where u used the `attributedText` in `action`

Comment: i think s not possible, we can add alertcontroller only not UIAlertAction

Comment: guard let label = (Camera.value(forKey: "__representer") as AnyObject) as? UILabel else { return }     label.attributedText = attributedText

Comment: its not working

Comment: attributedText is a private property of UIAlertController which Apple does not allow to change. It will work for a time being but Apple will reject at submission time.

Answer (score 4):

Reference form : [**Refer from Here**.](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/05/hacking-uialertcontroller-in-swift.html)

**Code :**

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert Title", message: "This is testing message.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    // Background color.
    let backView = alertController.view.subviews.last?.subviews.last
    backView?.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    backView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

    // Change Title With Color and Font:

    let myString  = "Alert Title"
    var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()
    myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString as String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 18.0)!])
    myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: NSRange(location:0,length:myString.characters.count))
    alertController.setValue(myMutableString, forKey: "attributedTitle")

    // Change Message With Color and Font

    let message  = "This is testing message."
    var messageMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()
    messageMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: message as String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 18.0)!])
    messageMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.greenColor(), range: NSRange(location:0,length:message.characters.count))
    alertController.setValue(messageMutableString, forKey: "attributedMessage")


    // Action.
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
    action.setValue(UIColor.orangeColor(), forKey: "titleTextColor")
    alertController.addAction(action)
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**OUTPUT :**

[image]

Comment: In the above link text colour is changing in alert action but i cant to add the custom font

Comment: @AmuthaKumari -  `alert action` has only proerty for chnage the `text colour` otherthing we can't handle

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik here is the soloution to set a custom font in swift https://github.com/okmr-d/DOAlertController

Comment: @AmuthaKumari - hey sister, is the customized UIViewController, by default UIAlertcontroller we can't handle, if we need we need to customize